# rigid body sim with keyframed objects

Tags: keyframes, rigid-body-simulation

I have a crate with keyframes set to passive. And a lot off balls with rigidbody set to active. I want the balls to drop in the crate and then leave the shot with the balls in the crate. Is there any way of doing this? I can't get it to work with keyframes. Do i have to bake it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just bake it. Then all your your rigid body objects get a keyframe for every frame you bake it and will loose the rigid body.

Comment: Didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! Check the "animated" switch in the rigid body settings in the physics tab. [image: blender physics tab]